# При изменении таблицы по условию CURRENT OF ошибка: ORA-01410: invalid ROWID

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, update, oracle19c

При выполнении скрипта приведённого ниже на [Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/) получаю ошибку:

> ORA-01410: invalid ROWID
>   ORA-06512: at line 24
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Ведь курсор должен указывать на конкретный `t2.rowid`, разве я не прав?

Тестовые данные:

```
create table t1 (
    id integer  primary key,
    val varchar2(100)
);

create table t2 (
    id integer  primary key,
    gr_id integer,
    val varchar2(100)
);

insert all
    into t1 values (1, 'A')
    into t1 values (2, 'B')
    into t1 values (3, 'C')

    into t2 values (1, 1, 'X11')
    into t2 values (2, 1, 'X21')
    into t2 values (3, 2, 'X32')
    into t2 values (4, 2, 'X42')
    into t2 values (5, 3, 'X53')
    into t2 values (6, 3, 'X63')
select * from dual;

commit;
```

Сам скрипт:

```
declare
    type t_rec is record (id integer, val t2.val%type);
    s_rec t_rec;
    cursor cur is
        select t1.id, t2.val
        from t1, t2
        where t2.gr_id = t1.id
        for update of t2.val nowait;
begin
    open cur;
        loop
            exit when cur%notfound;
            fetch cur into s_rec;

            update t2 set val = val||' Y'
            where current of cur;

        end loop;
    close cur;
end;
```

Comment: Уважаемый аноним, вы поставили -1 этому вопорсу. Объясните - за что вы поставили?

Comment: Да, совсем не понятно. Какой-то мусор плюсуют, а нормально оформленный вопрос с кодом и данными, который с копи-и-паста мгновенно воспроизводится, почему то минусуют.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В последей итерации цикла, когда курсор закончился и вернул атрибут `notfound=true`, произходит попытка измененения таблицы с недействительным `ROWID`.

Условие на выход из цикла всегда должно проверятся **сразу же после** `FETCH`:

```sql
fetch cur into s_rec;
exit when cur%notfound;
```